# R Shiny Dashboard running with no errors, but plots, datatable, and value boxes are not displaying

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, reactive, shinyapps

I am making an R Shiny Dashboard. The app runs fine, but my plots, data table, and value boxes are not showing up. I'm wondering if it's something with my reactive function on the server side? I made a regular shiny app similar to this and things worked fine.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(shinythemes)

#DATA MANIPULATION AND CLEANING 
food <- read_csv("food.csv", show_col_types = FALSE)
colnames(food)[colnames(food) == "Packging"] <- "Packaging" #Changing a misspelling
#Make a  new categorical variable for food product categories using case_when
food <- food %>%
  mutate(category = case_when(
    grepl("Beef|Lamb|Pig|Poultry|Fish", product, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "Meat/Seafood",
    grepl("Potato|Tomato|Citrus|Banana|Apple|Berries|Onions|Root Vegetables|Brassicas", product, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "Fruit/Vegetable",
    grepl("Dairy|Milk|Cheese|Eggs", product, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "Dairy/Eggs",
    TRUE ~ "Grain/Nut/Seed")
  )%>%
  relocate(category, .after = product)

#USER INTERFACE SIDE
ui <- dashboardPage(
                dashboardHeader(title = "Environmental Impact of Food Production",
                                titleWidth = 400),
                dashboardSidebar(
                  sidebarMenu(width = 2,
                              id = "tabs",
                              
                              #Page tabs
                              menuItem("Home", icon = icon("home"), tabName = "home"),
                              menuItem("Bar chart", icon = icon("bar-chart"), tabName = "bar"),
                              menuItem("Pie chart", icon = icon("chart-pie"), tabName = "pie"),
                              
                              #Inputs and filters
                              selectInput("y", "Select a variable for the y-axis of the histogram,
                                           bar chart, and pie chart breakdown:", 
                                           c("Land Use (Kg CO2)" = "Land_use",
                                             "Animal Feed (Kg CO2)" = "Animal_feed",
                                             "Farm (Kg CO2)" = "Farm",
                                             "Processing (Kg CO2)" = "Processing",
                                             "Transport (Kg CO2)" = "Transport",
                                             "Packaging (Kg CO2)" = "Packaging",
                                             "Retail (Kg CO2)" = "Retail",
                                             "Total Emissions (Kg CO2)" = "Total_emissions",
                                             "Eutrophying (per 100 kcal)" = "Eutrophying_emissions_kcal",
                                             "Eutrophying (per kilogram)" = "Eutrophying_emissions_kilogram",
                                             "Eutrophying (per 100g protein)" = "Eutrophying_emissions_protein",
                                             "Freshwater Withdrawals (per 100 kcal)" = "Freshwater_withdrawals_kcal",
                                             "Freshwater Withdrawals (per 100g protein)" = "Freshwater_withdrawals_protein",
                                             "Freshwater Withdrawals (per kilogram)" = "Freshwater_withdrawals_kilogram",
                                             "Greenhouse Gas (per 100 kcal)" = "Greenhouse_gas_kcal",
                                             "Greenhouse Gas (per 100g protein)" = "Greenhouse_gas_protein",
                                             "Land Use (per 100 kcal)" = "Land_use_kcal",
                                             "Land Use (per kilogram)" = "Land_use_kilogram",
                                             "Land Use (per 100g protein)" = "Land_use_protein",
                                             "Scarcity Weighted Water Use (per kilogram)" = "Scarcity_water_kilogram",
                                             "Scarcity Weighted Water Use (per 100g protein)" = "Scarcity_water_protein",
                                             "Scarcity Weighted Water Use (per 100 kcal)" = "Scarcity_water_kcal"),
                                           selected = "Land Use (Kg CO2)"),
                               selectInput("x", "Select a variable for the x-axis of the histogram:", 
                                           c("Land Use (Kg CO2)" = "Land_use",
                                             "Animal Feed (Kg CO2)" = "Animal_feed",
                                             "Farm (Kg CO2)" = "Farm",
                                             "Processing (Kg CO2)" = "Processing",
                                             "Transport (Kg CO2)" = "Transport",
                                             "Packaging (Kg CO2)" = "Packaging",
                                             "Retail (Kg CO2)" = "Retail",
                                             "Total Emissions (Kg CO2)" = "Total_emissions",
                                             "Eutrophying (per 100 kcal)" = "Eutrophying_emissions_kcal",
                                             "Eutrophying (per kilogram)" = "Eutrophying_emissions_kilogram",
                                             "Eutrophying (per 100g protein)" = "Eutrophying_emissions_protein",
                                             "Freshwater Withdrawals (per 100 kcal)" = "Freshwater_withdrawals_kcal",
                                             "Freshwater Withdrawals (per 100g protein)" = "Freshwater_withdrawals_protein",
                                             "Freshwater Withdrawals (per kilogram)" = "Freshwater_withdrawals_kilogram",
                                             "Greenhouse Gas (per 100 kcal)" = "Greenhouse_gas_kcal",
                                             "Greenhouse Gas (per 100g protein)" = "Greenhouse_gas_protein",
                                             "Land Use (per 100 kcal)" = "Land_use_kcal",
                                             "Land Use (per kilogram)" = "Land_use_kilogram",
                                             "Land Use (per 100g protein)" = "Land_use_protein",
                                             "Scarcity Weighted Water Use (per kilogram)" = "Scarcity_water_kilogram",
                                             "Scarcity Weighted Water Use (per 100g protein)" = "Scarcity_water_protein",
                                             "Scarcity Weighted Water Use (per 100 kcal)" = "Scarcity_water_kcal"),
                                           selected = "Greenhouse Gas Emissions per 100 kcal"),
                               sliderInput("emissions", "Pick a range of total emissions to filter food products in the dataset
                                           (this will also change the histogram):",
                                           min = 0, max = 60, value = c(0,10)),
                               #show data table
                               checkboxInput(inputId = "show_data",
                                             label = "Show data table",
                                             value = TRUE))),
                  
                  #Output - tabs
                  dashboardBody(
                    tabItems(
                      tabItem("home",
                        fluidRow(
                          valueBoxOutput("total_emissions"),
                          valueBoxOutput("x_total"),
                          valueBoxOutput("y_total")),
                        fluidRow(
                          plotOutput(outputId = "scatterplot")),
                        fluidRow(
                          DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "datatable"))),
                      tabItem("bar",
                              fluidRow(
                                plotOutput(outputId = "barchart")),
                              fluidRow(
                                DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "datatable"))),
                      tabItem("pie", 
                               fluidRow(
                                 plotOutput(outputId = "piechart")),
                               fluidRow(
                                 DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "datatable")))))
)

#SERVER SIDE
server <- function(input, output) {
  food_filtered <- reactive({
    req(input$y, input$x)
    food %>% 
      filter(Total_emissions >= input$emissions[1] & Total_emissions <= input$emissions[2]) %>% #filter based on the range on total emissions
      arrange(desc(!!sym(input$y))) #arrange by selected y (also what they will see on bar chart)
  })
  
  #Render the scatter plot 
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = food, aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y, color = "product")) +
      geom_point(size = 3) +
      labs(x = tools::toTitleCase(gsub("_", " ", input$x)),
           y = tools::toTitleCase(gsub("_", " ", input$y))
      ) +
      theme_classic() +
      theme(legend.position = "bottom")
  })
  # Render the bar chart
  output$barchart <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = food, aes_string(x = "category", y = input$y, fill = "category")) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
      xlab("Food Category") +
      ylab(ylab(tools::toTitleCase(gsub("_", " ", input$y)))) +
      ggtitle("Contribution of Different Food Categories to Selected Emission Type") +
      scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") +
      theme_classic() + 
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
  })
  # Render the pie chart
  output$piechart <- renderPlot({
    foodprod_sum <- aggregate(input$y ~ category, data = food, FUN = sum)
    names(foodprod_sum) <- c("Category", "Selected_emission")
    ggplot(data = foodprod_sum, aes(y = Selected_emission, fill = category)) +
      geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
      coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
      scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") +
      ggtitle("Selected Emission by Food Type") +
      xlab("") +
      ylab("Selected Emission") +
      theme(legend.position = "right",
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
      guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Food Category")) +
      theme_classic() +
      theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
      theme(axis.text = element_blank())
  })
  
  #Render data table on all tabs (if checked)
  output$datatable <- DT::renderDataTable(
    if(input$show_data){
      DT::datatable(data = food_filtered(), 
                    options = list(pageLength = 10), 
                    rownames = FALSE)
    }
  )
  
  #Render the value boxes 
  output$total_emissions <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      value = format(round(aggregate(Total_emissions ~ category,
                                     data = food, sum)$Total_emissions), nsmall = 2),
      subtitle = "Total Emissions",
      icon = icon("earth-americas"),
      color = "blue"
    )
  })
  
  output$y_total <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      value = format(round(sum(food$input[food$product == input$y]), nsmall = 2)),
      subtitle = tools::toTitleCase(gsub("_", " ", input$y)),
      icon = icon("fire"),
      color = "red"
    )
  })
  output$x_total <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      value = format(round(sum(food$input[food$product == input$x]), nsmall = 2)),
      subtitle = tools::toTitleCase(gsub("_", " ", input$x)),
      icon = icon("tree"),
      color = "green"
    )
  })
  
}

#run the dashboard
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Have tried picking out code piece by piece but the only thing that remains on the dashboard is the sidebar panel and tabs. It's difficult to figure out the issue without an error.

Sorry - here is the [link to the food csv](https://github.com/RforOperations2023/mehusseyHW2/blob/main/HW2/food.csv).

Comment: The use of `aes_string` is deprecated in `ggplot2 3.0.0`. You should use `aes` instead. Since there is no csv file provided, I tried to reproduce the code using a `food` dataframe generating a random data with all the column names shown in selectInput. I do not have the column product to color it and I do not know what to expect so I could not reproduce the ShinyApp. 

When you run the ggplots with `aes` instead of `aes_string` at least R is able to show a plot. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Actually, the sidebar and tabItems are the only thing showing up. The outputs themselves seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The app does not show the `tabItem` contents because it does not know how to render different elements sharing the same id. In shiny, different output id's should never repeat, no matter if they are identical. Replace your `dashboardBody` with this snippet to continue debugging your app (there seems to be some problems with your value boxes):

```
dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "home",
              fluidRow(
                valueBoxOutput("total_emissions"),
                valueBoxOutput("x_total"),
                valueBoxOutput("y_total")),
              fluidRow(
                plotOutput(outputId = "scatterplot")),
              fluidRow(
                DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "datatable1"))),
      tabItem(tabName = "bar",
              fluidRow(
                plotOutput(outputId = "barchart")),
              fluidRow(
                DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "datatable2")
                )),
      tabItem(tabName = "pie", 
              fluidRow(
                plotOutput(outputId = "piechart")),
              fluidRow(
                DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "datatable3"))
                )))
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks to @David's help - it was an issue of calling the same output ID! Appreciate the help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Glad I could help! this seems to be a little late, but please check my answer as correct to close this question.